# Journey Builder scheduled email a day before close date

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I have created a journey to scheduled email on the basis of opportunity stage.

I want to trigger the journey one day before the close date field.

Can you please help me how I can do the same?

Thanks
Praneet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to create a Date Based Event and set the entry criteria to be one day before the close date field.

[image: date based event]